# Unable to get message contents of email using google API

Tags: javascript, gmail

I'm trying to write some code in order to retrieve an email message using Google APIs. I followed the documentation provided here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22prashanthpillay2%40gmail.com%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22176d95971a2ffce1%22%7D, to implement my showMessageContent function and used the quickstart sample found here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs?authuser=1, but when I execute the code I only get the message ID displayed and nothing about the actual message. Any help would be great, I'm pretty new to this stuff.

Entire Code for my index.js file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
let messageArr = [];

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Gmail API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listMessages);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

async function listMessages(auth) {
  const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
  gmail.users.messages.list({
    userId: 'me',
    maxResults: 1
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const messages = res.data.messages;
    if (messages) {
      console.log('Messages:');
      let i=0;
      messages.forEach((message) => {
          messageArr[i] = message.id;
          console.log(messageArr[i]);
          i++;
      
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No messages found.');
    }

    
  }); 
  
  setTimeout(() => 
  {console.log(gmail.users.messages.get(
    {
      userId: 'me',
      id: '176daac2fedbf7f9'
    }, (err, res) => {
      if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      else{
        return res;
      }
      
    })
  );

  

  }, 3000);
```

}

Problem function:

```
    async function listMessages(auth) {
  const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
  gmail.users.messages.list({
    userId: 'me',
    maxResults: 1
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const messages = res.data.messages;
    if (messages) {
      console.log('Messages:');
      let i=0;
      messages.forEach((message) => {
          messageArr[i] = message.id;
          console.log(messageArr[i]);
          i++;
      
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No messages found.');
    }

    
  }); 
  
  setTimeout(() => 
  {console.log(gmail.users.messages.get(
    {
      userId: 'me',
      id: '176daac2fedbf7f9'
    }, (err, res) => {
      if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      else{
        return res;
      }
      
    })
  );

  

  }, 3000);

}
```

The result when I run it is in the attached picture

[image: Command Prompt Execution]

When the callback in setTimeout runs, it results in the result being undefined, which doesn't make sense to me since I passed the the correct ID manually to `gmail.users.messages.get()`.

Comment: It appears that everything is working. You dont get the error part, that is. The API call is simply returning the message IDs. You will need to do another request on those IDs to get the additional data you require, likely.

Comment: Well I may have said that prematurely. Your `listMessages()` as written, only outputs the IDs. ... While your `showMessageContent` call is lacking the `()` and also doesnt console log "Messages:" so I think your question code differs from your actual code?

Comment: Yes the listMessages() function is working correctly, but I have an issue with my showMessageContent() function

Comment: Back to `listMessages()`, why do you have a incremental loop inside a foreach on the same `messages`?

Comment: I say back to `listMessages()` because if that works, shouldnt that be your model for future code.

Comment: My understanding is that since messages is set to res.data.messages, messages is a variable containing information about all the messages. So when I do the foreach loop I can get the ID of every single message in messages. For testing purposes I set the maxResults to 1 so that I would only get 1 message ID.

Comment: But `messages.forEach()` already iterates each message .... I'm asking whats the point to have this `for( i = 0; i < messages.length; i++ )` inside the foreach handler, that does the same thing on `messages`?

Comment: In any event, I suggest doing a `console.log(message)` inside your foreach handler to see what properties/methods are available, and also comparing that to the API docs in question for further options

Comment: Really, that code you show is hard to read here in comments. Can you update your question with any code changes? Not just hard to read, but really needs to be in your question on "edits".

Comment: Yes for sure. That change doesn't do anything for the output though.

Comment: Ok. Well make the edits and since you say it doesnt change the output, possibly include your actual code because your image appears to reference `listMessages()` and not your `showMessageContent`. ... Upvoted you to maybe get you more attention, but I cant help you further if you question's code is not the same as what you are working with

Comment: Ok. Just Updated the Code. And the reason why my image seems to reference my list message function is because the console doesn't log anything when I call `showMessageContent;` which is what is confusing me

Comment: You need `()` to call your function. You have `showMessageContent;` but you need `showMessageContent();` with whatever necessary params in between `(` and `)`

Comment: Hi I attempted to do this but am still getting undefined when I try to output messageContent